# Free server hosting my application

Tags: java, hosting

i made an application in Java that needs to acess a database.
For now, im running it in tomcat on my computer and acessing in sql server on my computer too.

I would like to know if there is something free that i can host my application,and save data in a database too.
I mean,running this all out of my computer.

Any suggestions? thnks

Comment: Try openshift https://www.openshift.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Appfog](https://www.appfog.com/) allows you to deploy simple application for free. You have about 100 MB of DB storage space ([Full info](https://www.appfog.com/pricing/))

[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com) Gives you one free dyno for your app.

[Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) Has free plan as well. You get 3 gears.

Comment: weel ty for answers. Do u reccomend one? And about security?? it is safe?

Comment: Well, my biggest experience is with heroku. You use git as a way to deploy your app. It boots up immidiately. It has lots of various add-ons. I didn't come across anything that is not secure. I would recommend you to try this one out.